# javax.naming.NamingNotFoundException:jdbc/fc

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource, wildfly-10

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cpDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested 
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/fc

I am using wildfly 10 and Here is web.xml .

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
  <context-param id="ParamValue_1395228155626">
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/fc</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<servlet id="Init">
    <servlet-name>Init Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cedar.cp.utc.common.InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>reviewbudget</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>9</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

This is context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context crossContext="true" reloadable="true">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="java:jboss/jdbc/fc" auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
       driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl"
       username="C##user" password="windows7password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
       maxWait="-1"/> 
</Context>
```

Here is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<jee:jndi-lookup id="cpDataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/fc"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="oaDataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/fc"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="cpDataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl"/>
    <property name="username" value="C##user1"/>
    <property name="password" value="windows7password"/>
</bean>


</beans>
```

How can I fix this issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Spring, but is `context.xml` a Tomcat thing? WildFly definitely won't look for a `context.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But the wildfly look up the context.xml correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/fc</res-ref-name><!-- This should be available as java:comp/env/jdbc/fc in the JNDI context -->
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

So you can try putting this in  `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="cpDataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/fc"
expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="oaDataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/fc"
expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```